# How to find_or_initialize based on two fields when both fields correspond to possible uninitialized objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi guys I have a situation where on a form I'm taking in orders for a car servicing application. I have the following models:

```
Car
belongs_to :car_company

Car_company
has_many :cars

Services
attributes_accessible :car_company_id, :car_id
#virtual attributes
attributes_accessible :car_company_name, :car_reg
```

The thing is that on a single form the user can enter in the name of the car company as well as the registration number of a car. If the company name doesnt exist it creates a new company and associates it with the service and the same goes for the  car. I got this part working however the thing is that I want that on submitting this form the car created should be automatically associated with the car_company whether the carcompany exists or doesn't exist.

I'm pretty stuck here on how to get this thing done the right way? Its basically just to avoid having to enter the car details and the company details seperately just to use them on a form. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using an unconventional model name. By convention in rails, your model should be `CarCompany`. However, I think what you have will work.

Putting something like this in the appropriate controller may be something like what you want. If not, please clarify what you want.

```
car_company = Car_company.find_or_initialize_by_name(params[:car_company_name])
car = Car.find_or_initialize_by_registration(params[:car_registration])
car_company.cars << car
car_company.save
```

You actually may be able to combine the middle two lines with `car_company.cars.find_or...`, but I'm not sure if that works or not.

I hope that helps.